# Macro not working as required in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I have one macro, very simple one but I do not understand where is the problem? I got error:

> "Expected ; after expression"

This is a macro definition:

```
#define SEGCONTROL (itemArray, segmentedControl)      \
segmentedControl = [[SuperSegmentedControll alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];                                        \
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 28);     \
segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 05;              \
[segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1]];                  \
segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:62.0/255.0 blue:137.0/255.0 alpha:1];              [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];                                \
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:               @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected]; \
```

I am calling as below:

```
 NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Save", nil];
 SuperSegmentedControll *segmentedControl;
 SEGCONTROL(itemArray, segmentedControl);
```

I would like to create macro as similar code which is used at many places. For save, cancel ETC.

Comment: Why so complicated?  What's wrong with putting that stuff into a method or function?

Comment: Macros are overhead for compiler, Complex macros leads you to memory consumption too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this is failing is because there is a space between the `#define` macro name `SEGCONTROL` and the parameter list `(itemArray, segmentedControl)`. This is essentially defining `SEGCONTROL` as `(itemArray, segmentedControl)` rather than the code snippet. To resolve the issue simply remove the space after `SEGCONTROL`

```
#define SEGCONTROL(itemArray, segmentedControl) \ ...
```

**However** I would strongly recommend **against** using this approach, instead have a method on your `SuperSegmentedControll` class (which in turn should probably have a single L and a more descriptive name) that sets up the control. This way you will get better compiler checks. Something like this:

```
@implementation SuperSegmentedControl

- (instancetype)initWithItems:(NSArray *)items {
    self = [super initWithItems:items];
    if (self) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 28);
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 05;
        [self setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:62.0/255.0 blue:137.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        [self setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Which would be used as follows:

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Save", nil];
SuperSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[SuperSegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
```

Comment: Yup. This would be by far the most expected, standard way of doing it.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with Objective-C, the same macro would fail for the exact same reason in C, C++ and Objective-C++ as well.